# fedena installation error(ruby on rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, fedena

I am new to ruby and rails.I am trying to install fedena project.But on executing  `rdoc db:create` i am getting error like `failed to allocate memoryls/generators/rspec_controller/templates/helper_spec.rb`. I have already 4gb of ram in my system and in that 3.5 gb is free.How much memory is required for this ?Is it package intsallation bug?
I am using following rail ruby versions

```
Rail: Rails 2.3.5
Ruby:ruby 2.1.0
rake, version 10.1.1
rdoc-4.1.0
```

--debug

```
Parsing sources...
unable to convert "\xA7" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for public/javascripts/tiny_mce   /plugins/spellchecker/editor_plugin.js, skipping
unable to convert "\xA7" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for public/javascripts/tiny_mce/plugins/spellchecker/editor_plugin_src.js, skipping
failed to allocate memoryls/generators/rspec_controller/templates/helper_spec.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rdoc/parser/ruby_tools.rb:25:in `push'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rdoc/parser/ruby_tools.rb:25:in `get_tk'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rdoc/parser/ruby_tools.rb:132:in `skip_tkspace'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rdoc/parser/ruby.rb:428:in `get_constant_with_optional_parens'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rdoc/parser/ruby.rb:1072:in `block in parse_extend_or_include'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rdoc/parser/ruby.rb:1069:in `loop'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rdoc/parser/ruby.rb:1069:in `parse_extend_or_include'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rdoc/parser/ruby.rb:1725:in `parse_statements'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rdoc/parser/ruby.rb:1871:in `parse_top_level_statements'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rdoc/parser/ruby.rb:1999:in `block in scan'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rdoc/parser/ruby.rb:1997:in `catch'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rdoc/parser/ruby.rb:1997:in `scan'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rdoc/rdoc.rb:367:in `parse_file'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rdoc/rdoc.rb:420:in `block in parse_files'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rdoc/rdoc.rb:418:in `map'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rdoc/rdoc.rb:418:in `parse_files'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rdoc/rdoc.rb:488:in `document'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rdoc-4.1.0/bin/rdoc:20:in `<top (required)>'
    /usr/local/bin/rdoc:23:in `load'
    /usr/local/bin/rdoc:23:in `<main>'
```

Comment: http://projectfedena.org/install this link must be followed.. `rdoc db:create` ?

Comment: yes i followed.And i am using fedora.in that link its given steps for ubuntu.i have installed same packages for fedora.If am executing rake db:create am getting following error

Comment: If am executing rake db:create am getting following errorrake rake aborted!
ERROR: 'rake/rdoctask' is obsolete and no longer supported. Use 'rdoc/task' (available in RDoc 2.4.2+) instead.
/home/sathees/kits/fedena/fedena-v2.3-bundle-linux/Rakefile:8:in `<top (required)>'Thats why am  using rdoc

Comment: ERROR: 'rake/rdoctask' is obsolete and no longer supported is a common error google up..

Comment: Yes i tried to googling it and i m not able to solve the problem.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21158365/rake-dbcreate-error-in-fedena

Comment: Please specify your rails and ruby version .

Comment: @Arihant Godha I have edited my question and specified rail and ruby version.please check it out.

Comment: I guess the version should be `1.8.7` that's what i'm using to run fedena.. `2.1.0` is the latest

Comment: ok i will change it to 1.8.7 and check

Comment: I guess your ruby version and rails version are conflicting that are  required please do check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are using the wrong version of Ruby as of what they have specified in the documentation. Use rails as

> Rails 2.3.5(Note: Version should be 2.3.5),

ruby as

```
ruby-1.8.7-p302
```

In windows they are using this particular version of ruby 
[image: Check version]

Comment: @ArihaArihant Godha Ye i have changed ruby to 1.8.7. I am having some problems with gems.It showing rake aborted!
undefined method `task' for #<Spec::Rake::SpecTask:0xb72d136c>

Comment: @ArihaArihant Godha i tried to install gem install rspec-rails -v 1.3.2
No use.For latest rspec-rails, ruby 1.8.7 is not supporting