# Fedena Installation for Linux and Ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I am new to ruby on rails.While executing `rake db:create` i am getting following error.What is the problem.I found it is a common problem and googled it.I found to change rake version but my problem was not solved.

```
rake aborted!
ERROR: 'rake/rdoctask' is obsolete and no longer supported. Use 'rdoc/task' (available in RDoc 2.4.2+) instead.
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/rdoctask.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/home/sathees/kits/fedena/fedena-v2.3-bundle-linux/Rakefile:8:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:637:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in load_rakefile'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:93:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `block in run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/usr/local/bin/rake:33:in `<main>'
```

If i tried to replace require 'rake/rdoctask' to require 'rdoc/task'
am getting following error

```
rake aborted!
cannot load such file -- iconv
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/inflector.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/integer/inflections.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/integer.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/core_ext.rb:8:in `block in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/core_ext.rb:8:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/core_ext.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support.rb:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/tasks/misc.rake:18:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/tasks/rails.rb:4:in `load'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/tasks/rails.rb:4:in `block in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/tasks/rails.rb:4:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/tasks/rails.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/home/sathees/kits/fedena/fedena-v2.3-bundle-linux/Rakefile:11:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:637:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in load_rakefile'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:93:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `block in run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/usr/local/bin/rake:33:in `<main>'
```

Installed Gems

```
 gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (4.0.2)
actionpack (4.0.2)
activemodel (4.0.2)
activerecord (4.0.2)
activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3)
activesupport (4.0.2)
arel (4.0.1)
atomic (1.1.14)
bigdecimal (1.2.3)
builder (3.1.4)
bundler (1.5.2)
bundler-unload (1.0.2)
erubis (2.7.0)
executable-hooks (1.3.1)
gem-wrappers (1.2.4)
hike (1.2.3)
i18n (0.6.9, 0.4.0)
io-console (0.4.2)
json (1.8.1)
mail (2.5.4)
mime-types (1.25.1)
minitest (4.7.5)
multi_json (1.8.4)
polyglot (0.3.3)
psych (2.0.2)
rack (1.5.2)
rack-test (0.6.2)
rails (4.0.2)
railties (4.0.2)
rake (10.1.0)
rdoc (4.1.0)
rubygems-bundler (1.4.2)
rvm (1.11.3.8)
sprockets (2.10.1)
sprockets-rails (2.0.1)
test-unit (2.1.0.0)
thor (0.18.1)
thread_safe (0.1.3)
tilt (1.4.1)
treetop (1.4.15)
tzinfo (0.3.38)
```

Comment: In you application folder a File "Rakefile" has code : require orted!
ERROR: 'rake/rdoctask' so you have to replace this with require 'rdoc/task'. let me know if still have issue.

Comment: yes i have tried it and am gettig error which is posted in question.

Comment: means rake task issue solved and here is another issue , you can fix it by https://rvm.io/packages/iconv

Comment: `require 'iconv'
/usr/lib/ruby/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': iconv will be deprecated in the future, use String#encode instead.`
As you can see, support to `iconv` can be croppen out of ruby.but some gem still require the *iconv*, I gues it shell be updated to a new version, or the ruby version shell be downdraded to *1.9.3*, please show your **Gemfile**.

Comment: yes i did gem install iconv.Now problem is ther in cannot load such file -- spec/rake/spectask

Comment: @Neelesh i used rvm and installed latest version of ruby rails now while running rake db:create it shows Missing the Rails  gem. Please `gem install -v= rails`, update your RAILS_GEM_VERSION setting in config/environment.rb for the Rails version you do have installed, or comment out RAILS_GEM_VERSION to use the latest version installed.
but if am doing rails --version it shows Rails 4.0.2...If i commented that then also same issue

Comment: @majioa i have edited and posted all gem in question

Comment: You have to go to your application dir and select the ruby version by command $ rvm use runyversion (runyversion just for exm you have to get it by $ rvm list) and then create new gemset $ rvm gemeset create myapp and select that gemset by $ rvm gemset use myapp for my case and  now run $ bundle   .All will works. I hope

Comment: @Neelesh i tried all working fine.But for bundle command  its coming bash: bundle: command not found...My $PATH=bash: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@rails2.0.1/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p374/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/usr/lib/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/lib/ccache:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/sathees/.local/bin:/home/sathees/bin: No such file or directory

Comment: @Neelesh I tried gem install bundler now its coming Bundler::GemfileNotFound

Comment: @Neelesh All worked fine now i amgetting another issue undefined method `task' for #<Spec::Rake::SpecTask:0xb7319ea0>

Comment: include gem rspec-rails and do $ bundle install

Comment: @Neelesh: Finally got installed fedena.Thank u.You have been great healpful.Actually problem was there in rake.We have to installrake, version 0.9.2..And use gem 1.3.7.While switching from latest version of gem to gem 1.3.7 there was a conflict of bundler.Just uninstalled that bundler and then all worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fedena Installation In Linux**

```
1.1 Installing RVM

1. sudo gem install rvm

2. Put this lines in your .bash_profile or .bashrc:

if [[ -s $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm ]] ; then
        source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm
fi

1.2  Installing ruby inside your rvm
1. rvm install 1.8.7

1.3 - Setting up rvm to use your specific ruby version

1. rvm use 1.8.7 –default

1.4 - Installing rails 2.3.5

1. Create the gemset:rvm gemset create rails2
2.Setting up rvm to use always this gemset:
rvm use 1.8.7@rails2 –default
3.gem install rails -v 2.3.5

1.5 Setup your database details in the database.yml

1.6 Install the rest of the gems
1. gem install declarative_authorization -v 0.5.1
2. gem install i18n -v 0.4.2
3. gem install bundler

1.7 Downgrade your rake version to 10.1.0 to rake, version 0.9.2
1. gem uninstall rake -v 10.1.0
2. gem install rake -v 0.9.2

1.8 Update your Bundler 
1. bundle install

1.9 Install missing gems using gem install command:

gem install -v version no
Required gems 
gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (2.3.5)
actionpack (2.3.5)
activerecord (2.3.5)
activeresource (2.3.5)
activesupport (2.3.5)
atomic (1.1.14)
bundler-unload (1.0.2)
declarative_authorization (0.5.1)
executable-hooks (1.3.1)
fattr (2.2.1)
gem-wrappers (1.2.4)
i18n (0.4.2)
json (1.8.1)
minitest (4.7.5)
multi_json (1.8.4)
mysql (2.8.1)
pkg-config (1.1.5)
rack (1.0.1)
rails (2.3.5)
rake (0.9.2, 0.8.7)
rdoc (4.1.1)
rubygems-bundler (1.4.2)

rush (0.6.8)
rvm (1.11.3.8)
session (3.1.0)
test-unit (2.5.5)
thread_safe (0.1.3)
tzinfo (0.3.38)

1.10 Update your Bundler 
bundle install

1.11 :Edit your rake file from fedena project
vi fedena-v2.3-bundle-linux/Rakefile
Replace require 'rake/rdoctask' to require 'rdoc/task'

1.12 :Downgrade Your gem latest version to 1.3.7
gem update --system 1.3.7

1.13 :Now there will be a bundler conflict(latest version of gem and gem version 1.3.7) you should solve this using uninstalling bundler
Uninstalling bundler
rvm @global
gem list -d bundler1.5.2
rvm gemset use global && gem install bundler
bundle install
gem uninstall bundler(Uninstall all bundler which are installed)

1.14 Set up Fedena databases

From the Fedena source directory in terminal run, "rake db:create" followed by, "rake fedena:plugins:install_all" 

1.15 Change permissions for scripts

From the same directory grant executable permissions for the files in script directory by,
"chmod +x script/*" 

1.16 Run the inbuilt server

If everything went fine till now, you are ready to run fedena server by running the following from fedena source folder,
"script/server"

1.17 Finally, run the command "script/server".
This would start the server and it will be accessible at http://localhost:3000
```

**2 Fedena Installation In Ubuntu**

```
2.1 Setting up the Rails development environment

Ruby, rubygems, rails and other required packages can be installed by :
sudo apt-get install irb libopenssl-ruby libreadline-ruby rdoc ri ruby ruby-dev
cd /usr/local/src
wget http://production.cf.rubygems.org/rubygems/rubygems-1.3.7.tgz
tar xzvf rubygems-1.3.7.tgz
cd rubygems-1.3.7
sudo ruby setup.rb
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gem gem /usr/bin/gem1.8 1 
sudo gem install rails -v 2.3.5
2.2 Setting up MySQL server

Fedena uses mysql, so run,
"sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev mysql-server"
Do remember the mysql password you set during this step, it is required in step five.

2.3.Download the latest Fedena source code from github

Download Fedena source code from GitHub. Extract the downloaded .zip archive to a convenient location where you would be running fedena . Let us say we extracted it to a directory named fedena in my home(~) directory.

2.4.Setup your database details in the database.yml

Open the file database.yml in the config folder of the fedena soucre. Change the following details:
database: fedena - The name of the database you want to use for fedena
username: root - Mysql username for fedena
password: mypass - The password for the above mysql user 



2.5.Install the rest of the gems

"gem install declarative_authorization -v 0.5.1" 
"gem install i18n -v 0.4.2" 

2.6 Downgrade your rake version to 10.1.0 to rake, version 0.9.2
3. gem uninstall rake -v 10.1.0
4. gem install rake -v 0.9.2

2.7 Edit your rake file from fedena project
vi fedena-v2.3-bundle-linux/Rakefile
Replace require 'rake/rdoctask' to require 'rdoc/task'

2.8. Set up Fedena databases 

From the Fedena source directory in terminal run, "rake db:create" followed by, "rake fedena:plugins:install_all" 

2.9 Change permissions for scripts

From the same directory grant executable permissions for the files in script directory by,
"chmod +x script/*" 

2.10 Run the inbuilt server

If everything went fine till now, you are ready to run fedena server by running the following from fedena source folder,
"script/server"
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply you need to downgrade your rake from 10.x.x to 1.8.7

Here is how you can do it:

1. gem uninstall rake
2. gem install rake -v=1.8.7

A complete guild for Fedena Installation is available over here:

[Installing Fedena on CentOS, Debian & Ubuntu](http://www.betamakers.com/Community/ForumPosts.asp?TID=30&title=installing-fedena-on-centos-debian-ubuntu)